# Building a hello world project for a Verifone Terminal using Sourcery CodeBench for Verifone DTK

Tags: eclipse, verifone

I am attempting to flash a basic hello world program to a Verifone terminal as an exercise in the development flow of the hardware. I'm currently running into an issue that is occurring somewhere during the post-build steps. After I build my project, I get the message:

```
***
*** The package '\Debug\dl.lab2.tar' is available for download.
***
```

Implying that the project built successfully. However, further up in the build messages, I can see:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Verifone\PackageManagerProduction\Cygwin\tar.exe" -czf "usr1.bundle.lab2.tgz" "pkg.lab2.tar" "pkg.lab2.tar.p7s" "crt" -C "..\bundle" "./"
tar (child): gzip: Cannot exec: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

And indeed, when I try to load the resulting archive, I get the "Invalid bundle file" on the PinPad. Inspecting the dl.lab2.tgz file shows that one of the internal archives is actually 0 Kb, so I'm quite positive it's because this archive generation step is failing. I'm not sure why it's failing though, because checking the directory contents, it seems like everything that it's looking for is there, though I can't explain why it's searching for "./". Does anyone have an idea why this is failing, and can someone tell me if it is possible to edit this archive generation step through CodeBench?

Comment: I've partially answered my own question. The post-build packaging steps are occurring in the simple_pkg.bat file located under the postscripts directory of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my answer to this, so I'll post an answer to hopefully help someone else in the future. I was correct in assuming that the error being returned by tar.exe was suspect. The post-build steps were being executed by running the external script simple_pkg.bat. Apparently the path in the simple_pkg.bat script was completely wrong; it was just pointing to an executable that didn't exist. Modifying simple_pkg.bat to point to where the correct tar.exe files was fixed my issue.